# Recommendation on Javascript Observer Pattern?

Tags: visualforce, javascript, lightning-aura-components

Javascript models become more and more important. In different scenarios I'm encountering the challenge to have a Javascript object model, which has to be synchronized n-ways e. g. to different UI components as well as to other models like localStorage or IndexedDB.

Lets say we have

```
foo = { bar : 77 };
```

now we want a callback to be fired everytime someone updates the property like this:

```
for.bar = 88;
```

(assume we don't want to use getters and setters...)

In an ideal world we would have Object.observe() - but not all browsers support it at this time. Object.observe() is part of the future ECMAScript 7 proposal. It seems actually be supported in Chrome, but not in Firefox, Safari and IE.

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/observe
- http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es7/observe/
- http://arv.github.io/ecmascript-object-observe/

I'm looking for a cross-browser solution working right NOW and acting like Object.observe().

As far as I understand, emulation is done by lots of frameworks like Angular, Knockout, etc. using a technique called "dirty-checking". The ideal solution would be a small lightweight shim which somehow emulates a comparable solution in legacy browsers where the native Object.observe() is not available and dynamically uses the native implementation if present.

So far I found different approaches:

- use one of the "bigger" frameworks like Angular, Knockout - but for this single requirement possibly oversized
- https://github.com/jdarling/Object.observe
- https://github.com/MaxArt2501/object-observe
- http://techblog.personalcapital.com/2013/02/js-hacks-dead-simple-javascript-variable-change-watchers/
- https://github.com/polymer/observe-js

Before I dig very deep into evaluation myself, I would like to ask if anyone faced a similar challenge and maybe has experience or recommendations about any of these currently available workarounds?

Update:

My very first impression is that https://github.com/polymer/observe-js does not work and https://github.com/MaxArt2501/object-observe seems to work...

Comment: I think this question is much better placed at stackoverflow where real programmers loiter about.
Anyway - if you definitely want an opinion of someone damaged by SFDC ecosystem, here it is - unless you want to implement (**and maintain**) your own observable just for the sake of "look - I have done it",  I'd use "bigger"frameworks like AngularJS or [Ember](http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/bindings/). IMHO - these days (for most requirements) there are very few reasons to use visualforce for anything other than bootstrapping your application for a modern framework.

Comment: Uwe, I have to agree with @gaiser. This question really belongs in StackOverflow.

Comment: Thanks for your opinions. Agreed with destination StackOverflow, but I would like to keep it here too, since it could be helpful for some simple use cases. I found that https://github.com/MaxArt2501/object-observe is quite usable at this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this time https://github.com/MaxArt2501/object-observe looks sufficient for the stated requirements. It seems even to use Object.observe() if available and only degrades to its own (way slower) implementation when really necessary. So it won't slow down Chrome now. It has some "Limitations and caveats" (see link above) but since the "big" frameworks also use "dirty checking", it's possibly very similar.

Nice side-effect: when the other browsers learn Object.observe(), you can leave your code untouched. It will shift to the native implementation seamlessly ;-)