# Nameclash: http://aurajs.com in not https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura

Today I searched for "aura js" via Google and in the searchbox at Github and got results pointing to http://aurajs.com - which does not work:

> Site Disabled
>
> Oh no! It looks like this Pages site has been disabled due to a
>   misconfigured custom domain.
>
> Are you the site owner? You can quickly fix this issue by updating the
>   DNS record for your Pages site:
>
> If you're using a subdomain (coolthing.example.com, www.example.com,
>   etc.), make sure you have a CNAME record that points to
>   your-username.github.io. If you're not using a subdomain
>   (example.com), make sure you have two A records set to the following
>   IPs: 192.30.252.153 and 192.30.252.154

It seems to be an IP deprecation as described here:

https://github.com/blog/1917-github-pages-legacy-ip-deprecation

@salesforce: is it possible to fix this?

**UPDATE:**

It was my fault and the reason seems to be an unfortunate naming clash as @Peter said below. The Aura-Website is not http://aurajs.com but instead is available at https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura

Since naive searches for "aura js" via google or even at github in the search-box leads to the wrong http://aurajs.com I would recommend to keep this question as it may help others for finding the right URL.

Comment: Are you trying to get to the aura documentation from the github site?

Comment: Just want to look into the aura code and doc on how it deals with Object.observe() or pub/sub pattern in context of this research:  http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/64908/recommendation-on-javascript-observer-pattern

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I don't believe this URL is for any of the Salesforce oriented aura assets. This site is another JS project that happens to be named 'Aura'.

Comment: I fully agree with keeping the question. Having it is useful for the purposes of helping misguided people, whether looking for "our" Aura, or "theirs". Closing the question does not take it out of circulation. It merely prevents further answer and closes discussion. I have run across other closed questions on other SE's. I'm sure this is just the first go of them/us.

Comment: Might I suggest you update the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks @Peter for the heads up! The name aura is really a tricky one. But now it should be finally clarified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Salesforce Aura open source project that the Force.com Lightning Component Framework is based upon is found in the following location on github:

https://github.com/forcedotcom/aura

There is a link to access the documentation in the README there, but the direct link is as follows:

http://documentation.auraframework.org/auradocs#

Incidentally, if you go to the tag wiki for the `aura` tag in Salesforce StackExchange, you will find links to the same there: 
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tags/aura/info

Comment: No I see it is a naming clash... I updated my question since this my also happen to others who look for the salesforce-related aura...

Answer (score 2):

You can get the documentation and code here: https://github.com/aurajs/aura. You can either clone the repository to your desktop or download the repository as a ZIP-file by using the buttons on the right.

**Update:** For the Salesforce Aura open source project, please refer to Peter's answer

Comment: Thx, now I see the repo there. Just all searches via google or even inside github itself lead me to the old url...

Comment: That's not the Salesforce aura project, actually.

Comment: This isn't the Salesforce aura project. Unfortunate name clash, but going to that link won't help you answer lightning component questions.